# Is it possible to convert game written in Torque Game Engine 1.5.1 into Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, torque3d

I have some games written several years ago in Torque (so C++ engine code and Torque scripts). I'd like to have them in Unity3D.
I have searched through the Internet but haven't found anything.
Is rewriting everything from the scratch the only way to convert those games from TGE 1.5.1 into Unity?
I know that I can import some graphics but I cannot find anything about code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is the only way. Not only do they use different languages, but also different concepts to reason about game logic and different coding practices.

Comment: This is what I actually thought. Thank you for a prompt response.